# Error with my FLASK API after being deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, jupyter-notebook

My Heroku APP dosen't works if someone knows why.

My app :

```
# Import libraries
from flask import Flask, request
import mlflow
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/',methods=['POST'])

def predict():

    # Get the data from the POST request.
    data = request.get_json()
    
    # Make prediction using model loaded from disk as per the data.
    prediction = np.array2string(model.predict_proba(data)) 
    
    # Take the first value of prediction    
    return prediction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load the model
    model = pickle.load(open('ModelGrid.sav', 'rb'))
    #model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model(model_uri)
    
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

My requests on jupyter notebook :

**Localy :**

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'

data = New_Data.values.tolist()
j_data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=j_data, headers=headers)
result2 = float(r.text.split(' ')[1].split(']]')[0])
int(round(result2,2)*100)
```

==> This code working in local.

**After deployement on Heroku**:
I don't have an error with the deployement.
But whent I tried this :

```
url = 'https://prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com/api/'

data = New_Data.values.tolist()
j_data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=j_data, headers=headers)
result2 = float(r.text.split(' ')[1].split(']]')[0])
int(round(result2,2)*100)
```

I have this error :

```
'<!doctype html>\n<html lang=en>\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\n'
```

I tried with this 3 things :

- ```
  app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
  ```
- ```
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
  ```
- or with no line

But I always have the same error.

On github I have :

- My app
- A procfile with this :

```
web: gunicorn Flask:app
```

My app is Flask.py

- A requirements.txt (for streamlit to) with that :

```
streamlit
pandas
seaborn
numpy
requests
mlflow
plotly
numba
shap
ipython
Flask
gunicorn
lightgbm
```

- A runtime.txt with that:

```
python-3.11.4
```

The build log :

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt  !       !     A Python security update is available! Upgrade as soon as possible to: python-3.11.5  !     See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes  !     
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.11.4
-----> Installing pip 23.2.1, setuptools 68.0.0 and wheel 0.41.0
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 324.3M
-----> Launching...  !     Warning: Your slug size (324 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.
       Released v32
       https://prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

The log :

```
2023-09-08T09:42:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:42:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:44:36.848743+00:00 app[api]: Release v33 created by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:44:36.848743+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0db81ca9 by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:44:39.742711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-09-08T09:44:39.806120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-09-08T09:44:40.613664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-09-08T09:44:40.641689+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:40 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-09-08T09:44:40.641702+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:40 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-09-08T09:44:40.641703+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:40 +0000] [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-08T09:44:41.144182+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:41 +0000] [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-09-08T09:44:41.274312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-09-08T09:44:54.562453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Flask:app`
2023-09-08T09:44:55.447835+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:55 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-08T09:44:55.448144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:55 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7202 (2)
2023-09-08T09:44:55.448190+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:55 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-09-08T09:44:55.450549+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:55 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-09-08T09:44:55.475569+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:44:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-09-08T09:44:55.876481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-09-08T09:45:13.673282+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0db81ca9 by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:45:13.673282+00:00 app[api]: Release v34 created by user johan.rocheteau@hotmail.fr
2023-09-08T09:45:14.851032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-09-08T09:45:14.917793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-09-08T09:45:15.716318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-09-08T09:45:15.740463+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:15 +0000] [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-08T09:45:15.740493+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:15 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-09-08T09:45:15.741082+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:15 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-09-08T09:45:16.141196+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:16 +0000] [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-09-08T09:45:16.235229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-09-08T09:45:29.479733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Flask:app`
2023-09-08T09:45:30.252293+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:30 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-08T09:45:30.252530+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:30 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56968 (2)
2023-09-08T09:45:30.252578+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:30 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-09-08T09:45:30.254462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:30 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-09-08T09:45:30.327026+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:45:30 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-09-08T09:45:30.697227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-09-08T09:45:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-09-08T09:46:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-09-08T09:46:32.703777+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.4.1 - - [08/Sep/2023:09:46:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0"
2023-09-08T09:46:32.704000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com request_id=5da02091-31c8-48ec-8a64-b2f9fef86013 fwd="90.114.107.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=368 protocol=https
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:46:43,842] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/ [POST]
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843166+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843166+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843167+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843167+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843168+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843168+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843169+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843169+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843169+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843169+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843170+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Flask.py", line 17, in predict
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843171+00:00 app[web.1]: prediction = np.array2string(model.predict_proba(data))
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843171+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843171+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'model' is not defined
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/" host=prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com request_id=d9555431-3df0-4efa-80ad-924c2b7438cf fwd="90.114.107.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=438 protocol=https
2023-09-08T09:46:43.843649+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.41.223 - - [08/Sep/2023:09:46:43 +0000] "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0"
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463845+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:47:09,462] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/ [POST]
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463860+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463862+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463862+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463864+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463864+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463864+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463865+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463865+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463865+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463865+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463866+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463866+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463866+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Flask.py", line 17, in predict
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463867+00:00 app[web.1]: prediction = np.array2string(model.predict_proba(data))
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463867+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:47:09.463868+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'model' is not defined
2023-09-08T09:47:09.464440+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.21 - - [08/Sep/2023:09:47:09 +0000] "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0"
2023-09-08T09:47:09.464448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/" host=prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com request_id=79fef135-d61d-43ee-86a8-ccb153a1b909 fwd="90.114.107.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=438 protocol=https
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334080+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-09-08 09:55:38,333] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/ [POST]
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334097+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334099+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334099+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334099+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334101+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334101+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334102+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334102+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334102+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334103+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334103+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334103+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Flask.py", line 17, in predict
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334105+00:00 app[web.1]: prediction = np.array2string(model.predict_proba(data))
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334105+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334105+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'model' is not defined
2023-09-08T09:55:38.334620+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.7.143 - - [08/Sep/2023:09:55:38 +0000] "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0"
2023-09-08T09:55:38.335053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/" host=prediction-app-p7-6a2e12152edf.herokuapp.com request_id=e124c48b-2d55-40ec-9c56-2fbb334daedd fwd="90.114.107.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=438 protocol=https
```

If you have any idea please.

Comment: Can you provide the traceback (error logs) from your heroku instance?

Comment: Thanks for your help I find the answer with finding how I can find the log error. In local you can have the model load after the def but in deployement you need ton have the answer befor. I don't know why.